# ListView Inside CardView not Showing its full length

Tags: android

Hellow i've implemented ListView inside the CardView but now what problem i got is, the CardView is not Expanding on Adding list item. Can anybody help me,how to slove the issue? I have gone through different posts on stackoverflow but cannot find the solution :( My code is below

//this is my Listview adapter Class

```
public class EmploymentHistoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public ArrayList<EmploymentHistory> mEmploymentHistories;
private Context context;

public EmploymentHistoryAdapter(ArrayList<EmploymentHistory> mEmploymentHistories, Context context) {
    this.mEmploymentHistories = mEmploymentHistories;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mEmploymentHistories.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = null;
    EmploymentHistory empHistory = mEmploymentHistories.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_employee_history_row, parent, false);
    } else {

        v = convertView;

    }
    TextView hospital = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hospital);
    TextView department = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.department);
    TextView startDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.startDate);
    TextView endDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.endDate);

    TextView hospitalName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hospitalName);
    hospitalName.setText(empHistory.getHospital());
    TextView departmentName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.departmentName);
    departmentName.setText(empHistory.getDepartment());
    TextView startDate1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.startDate1);
    startDate1.setText(empHistory.getStartDate());
    TextView endDate1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.endDate1);
    endDate1.setText(empHistory.getEndDate());

    hospital.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    department.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    startDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    endDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return v;
}
```

}

//this is where i populated the ListView

```
 private void populateEmploymentHistoryList() {
    listEmployeeHistory = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listEmployeeHistory);

    empHistory = dbHelper.getAllEmploymentHistory();
    employmentHistoryAdapter = new EmploymentHistoryAdapter(empHistory,this);
    listEmployeeHistory.setAdapter(employmentHistoryAdapter);
}
```

//this is my Layout file where i added the ListView and I have the custom design for list_row

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/employmentHistoryCard"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/employmentHistory"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="#E0E0E0"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Employment History"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                    android:textColor="#4A148C" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/addEmployment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/employmentHistory"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_add"
                    android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_add"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="Add Employment"
                    android:textColor="#0e89d0" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listEmployeeHistory"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/addEmployment">

                </ListView>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify certain height for ListView in the xml code. WRAP_CONTENT will not expand your ListView when data is inflated into it. Specify some height like 200dp or something.

Comment: ya it works but the case is different. There wont be same list row for different user. your answer works if there is limited number of List item.

Comment: Can you give me any other effective solution?? This wont work for me

Comment: You can do one thing. Set the height dynamically depending on your requirement for each item of RecyclerView.  This way, your ListViews will have a height as per the requirement of each item in the RecyclerView.